# PlaceAutocomplete widget doesn't work in Android 4.1

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

[PlaceAutocomplete widget](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/12/autocomplete-widget-and-updated-place.html) works fine in Android 5.0, but nothing happens with 4.1 when openAutocomplete has been called. No errors in LogCat. onActivityResult performed, but with null in data param. What is the problem?

Code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(activity, data)

            val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.latLng)
            // map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)

            if (action === AddressPickerType.FROM) {
                activity.order.from.onNext(place)
            } else {
                activity.order.to.onNext(place)
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            val status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(activity, data)
            Log.e(App.tag, "Error: Status = " + status.toString())
        }
        else if (resultCode == FragmentActivity.RESULT_CANCELED) {}
    }
}

fun openAutocomplete() {
    val intent = PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
        .build(activity)

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

p.s. sorry for my English

Comment: Could you edit your question by adding your *PlaceAutoComplete builder* code?

Comment: @regmoraes PlaceAutocomplete class? It's a part of play-services-location-8.4. Decompiled class [looks like this](https://gist.github.com/RevanScript/2ceb56ffbc285e294ff92eea44663e89)